# Check if a Dataframe is empty, python

Tags: databricks, catalog

I am trying to check if a Dataframe has data inside:

The code is:

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM pts_dev.data_quality.rpa where family = '{0}' and mm_aaaa_ref = '{1}'".format(family,mm_aaaa))
display(df)

if df is not None:
    print("no empty")
else:
    print("empty")
```

The **df** does not have any result (is empty), but the message I got is **not empty**.  I think my error is when I define df,  I have tried ***if (len)df is not None:*** but it says that ***Dataframe has no len()***

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that simply by **df.isEmpty()**
Ref:https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.isEmpty.html#pyspark-sql-dataframe-isempty

Comment: Thank you very much.  It was so simply and I didn´t see it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```py
if df.count() > 0: # no empty
    print("no empty")
else: # empty
    print("empty")
```